# How can I determine the escape sequence for characters in an icon font?

Tags: css, fonts

I am working with a theme which uses a custom built set of icons which are loaded as a font.  If I download the font I can load it in my font manager and see all the icons, but how to determine which escape sequence to use in my css to render a particular icon?  Is there a utility or some way to translate icons to their relative escape codes?

Comment: OS X preferably but I have access to windows and linux as well

Comment: Okay, answer for Windows below.  HTH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows:

Start -> All Programs -> Accessories -> System Tools -> Character Map

Select the font, the select the character.  The character code will be shown in the status bar at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks.. I will be accepting this in a moment.  For the record, this got me looking on the right track.  I found if I copy the character in OS X font book and paste it into the character view search box it returns a message like "PRIVATE USE AREA-E059" which is the escape code I wanted.  Kinda convoluted but got what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would add an answer here for Mac users since Lance's suggestion led me to a solution that works on OS X.

Make sure you have Character Viewer enabled in the menubar.  (Open System Preferences > Keyboard, and tick "Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar")

Now open the font file in Font Book, copy the character in font book preview and then paste it into the character viewer search box.  This will return a message like "PRIVATE USE AREA-E059" which is the escape code you need to use in your CSS.